# Can anyone help me with this sql query

Tags: java, sql

I have the following code with a SQL query in `PreparedSentence`:

```
public final ProductInfoExt getProductInfoByCode(String sCode, String siteGuid) throws BasicException {
    if (sCode.startsWith("977")) {
        // This is an ISSN barcode (news and magazines) 
        // the first 3 digits correspond to the 977 prefix assigned to serial publications, 
        // the next 7 digits correspond to the ISSN of the publication 
        // Anything after that is publisher dependant - we strip everything after  
        // the 10th character 
        sCode = sCode.substring(0, 10);
    }
    return (ProductInfoExt) new PreparedSentence(s, "SELECT "
            + getSelectFieldList()
            + " FROM STOCKCURRENT AS C RIGHT JOIN PRODUCTS P ON (C.PRODUCT = P.ID) "
            + " WHERE P.CODE OR (P.REFERENCE = ? ) AND C.SITEGUID = ? ",
            new SerializerWriteBasicExt(new Datas[]{Datas.OBJECT, Datas.STRING, Datas.OBJECT, Datas.STRING}, new int[]{0, 1}),
            ProductInfoExt.getSerializerRead()).find(sCode, siteGuid);
}
```

It works great if I use search through `P.CODE`: `WHERE P.CODE = ? AND C.SITEGUID = ?`. However, lets say I want it to find a result in `P.REFERENCE` if  nothing matches in `P.CODE`. I tried doing a code statement like this with no success: `WHERE P.CODE OR P.REFERENCE = ? AND C.SITEGUID = ?`, but I received an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE P.CODE OR (P.REFERENCE = ? )` - where p.code what ?

Comment: Grammar and inline code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group your `OR` statement

```
return (ProductInfoExt) new PreparedSentence(s, "SELECT "
        + getSelectFieldList()
        + " FROM STOCKCURRENT AS C RIGHT JOIN PRODUCTS P ON (C.PRODUCT = P.ID) "
        + " WHERE (P.CODE = ? OR P.REFERENCE = ?) AND C.SITEGUID = ? ",
        new SerializerWriteBasicExt(new Datas[]{Datas.OBJECT, Datas.STRING, Datas.OBJECT, Datas.STRING, Datas.OBJECT, Datas.STRING}, new int[]{0, 1, 2}),
        ProductInfoExt.getSerializerRead()).find(sCode, sCode, siteGuid);
```

Comment: just made change but i get this error java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3

Comment: you need to update your Data objects, please try above code

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be

```
WHERE (P.CODE = ?  OR P.REFERENCE = ?) AND C.SITEGUID = ?
```

And then you will need to set the third parameter

Comment: thank you villat for your comment, how do i set the third parameter?

Comment: Could you try changing **new int[]{0, 1}** into **new int[]{0, 0, 1}** ?